# Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT' and 'WHERE'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I can't figure out what's wrong with my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE duplicatecheck2
    @QmemberID INT,
    @InputDate DATE
AS
    INSERT INTO tbl_availableMembers 
        SELECT memberId 
        FROM tbl_attendancesheet
        WHERE MemberId = @QmemberId
          AND [date] = @InputDate
          AND [clockin] IS NOT NULL
          AND [clockout] IS NULL

   UNION

   INSERT INTO tbl_availableMembers 
       SELECT memberId 
       FROM tbl_attendancemembers
       WHERE memberId NOT IN (SELECT memberId 
                              FROM tbl_attendanceSheet)
       WHERE date = @InputDate)
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure duplicatecheck2, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Insert'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure duplicatecheck2, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

My other stored procedure that union has worked in it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE duplicateCheck
    @inputdate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tbl_availableMembers

    INSERT INTO tbl_availableMembers 
        SELECT memberId
        FROM tbl_attendancemembers
        WHERE memberId NOT IN (SELECT memberId FROM tbl_attendanceSheet)
        UNION
        SELECT memberId
        FROM tbl_attendancemembers
        WHERE memberId IN (SELECT memberId 
                           FROM tbl_attendanceSheet
                           GROUP BY memberId, date
                           HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1 AND date = @inputdate)
END
```

Comment: You **cannot** apply the `UNION` to two `INSERT`  statements (as in your first code snippet) - but you **can** apply it to two `SELECT` statements (as in your second code sample)

Comment: Wow :O good point. I didn't know it. Thank you. You saved my day ^__^

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the "UNION". The stored procedure can just run two insert statements.

Noel

Comment: You were right but I need the result of two queries unified with the union. if I delete it I won't be able to achieve that. beside, I have used union in another store procedure no problem what is the reason that union is making trouble here?

Comment: I will copy the store procedure that union has worked in it.

Comment: OK, but your working example you have just one Insert statement. So try unioning your Select statements, but with just one Insert. See if that works.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the UNION to two INSERT statements (as in your first code snippet) - but you can apply it to two SELECT statements (as in your second code sample)
By @marc_s